# Fortran, How do I get Fortran to ignore lines from a data file that has random spacing

Tags: input, fortran, skip

I am writing a FORTRAN code that uses data in a file made by a MD program. the data is a list of values but has breaks in the data for list updates in the form (# Neighbor list update ..    6527 indexes in list),   These breaks are at random intervals so I can't just skip every x

I when I do my code it doesn't ignore these lines and randomly adds the value from the previous step.

1,  0.98510699999999995,       0.98510699999999995
           2,   1.9654170000000000,       0.98031000000000001
           3,   2.9427820000000002,       0.97736500000000004
           4,  3.9186540000000001,       0.97587199999999996
           4, 4.8945259999999999,       0.97587199999999996
           5,   5.8697910000000002,       0.97526500000000005
*note the double step 4 with an identical value from the true step 4*

How would I go about skipping this line. Please find the sample code below

```
Open(Unit=10,File='prod._100.tup')

do i=1,50

Read(10,*,IOSTAT=ios)step,temp,kinetic,potential,total,pressure
If(IS_IOSTAT_END(ios)) Exit
test=test+temp
print*, step, test, temp
End Do
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what the "breaks" in the file are.   Are they blank lines?   If so, the following code should work:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env

character (len=200) :: line

Open(Unit=10,File='prod._100.tup')

read_loop: do

   Read (10,'(A)',IOSTAT=ios) line
   If(ios == iostat_end) exit read_loop
   if (len_trim (line) == 0) then
      write (*, *) "blank line"
      cycle read_loop
   end if
   read (line, *) step,temp,kinetic,potential,total,pressure
   test=test+temp
   print*, step, test, temp

end do: read_loop

write (*, *) "total is", test
```

The above is not tested.  The "len_trim" test is based on bad records being blank lines. If breaks are otherwise defined you will have to create a different test.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
i=1
do while (i<=50)
  Read(10,*,IOSTAT=ios)step,temp,kinetic,potential,total,pressure
  If(IS_IOSTAT_END(ios)) Exit
  IF(ios.ne.0) cycle
  test=test+temp
  i=i+1
enddo
```

When a bad record is read, ios is assigned a system dependent non-zero number  (it is zero on success).  Apparently you've written a function (IS_IOSTAT_END) to tell if you've reached the end of the file, but other error conditions can exist (for example, the read statement doesn't match the data).  That will return a different non-zero ios than an end-file record, so you should just restart the loop at that point (e.g. `cycle`)

I assume you want to read exactly 50 lines from the file, so I changed your `do` loop to a `do while`, but if the number of records you read doesn't actually matter, then feel free to change it back.